# summation of a series in which each term is product of nth term of two sequence

Tags: summation

Is it possible to find the sum $\Sigma_{x=1}^n ((2x)(4x+1))$?  If yes then can somebody please explain for me the formula?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange! Please try and format your question properly so that it makes it easier for others to answer. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a guide for formatting equations. Also show us what you have tried and your thoughts on the problem so we can help you more effectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are well-known formulas for $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$, $\sum_{k=1}^n k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, $\sum_{k=1}^n 1=n$, from which you can combine your result.